# The $3\times3$ matrix $M$ with $M_{ij}=a_ia_j+\mathbf 1_{i=j}$ has determinant $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+1$

Tags: determinant

I would like to show that

$$
\det \pmatrix{
a^2+1 & ab & ac \\
ab & b^2+1 & bc \\
ac & bc & c^2+1
} = a^2+b^2+c^2+1
$$

Is there a trick or do I need to calculate the determinant the ugly way?

Comment: [trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity).

Comment: What 'tricks' have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the "ugly way" is not too tricky, because there are some easy intermediate cancellations. Expanding using the first row gives $$(a^2+1)(b^2+c^2+1)-ab(ab)+ac(-ac)=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$$

Comment: You are totally right. In mathematics, not everything is as compilcated as it looks like.

Comment: @Marcel Of course the formula generalises to many dimensions using the "tricks" people have pointed out - there is a limit to computing such things by hand!

Answer (score 6):

If $A$ is that matrix, and we let $v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$, then we notice that $Ax = (v\cdot x)v+x$ for all vectors $x$. In particular, $Av=(|v|^2+1)v$ whereas $Aw=w$ for $w\perp v$. Thus, we can express $A$ with respect to a suitable basis $v,w_1,w_2$ as
$$\begin{pmatrix}|v|^2+1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} $$
which obviously has determinant $|v|^2+1=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's just $$\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+1)+2a^2b^2c^2-\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2(c^2+1)=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$$